# trouble with flicker api jquery method .coinslider();

Tags: jquery, api, flickr

hey guys this code seems to really be right and I'm just for the life of me not sure what its not working for me. I'm using the flickr api to take down some photos and put them in a coinslider with jquery. The images come down fine, but no coinslider(); //!!!!

here is the code I'm working with for this:

index.js

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",{tags: "wild",tagmode: "any", format: "json" },
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                console.log(item)
                $("<img/>").attr({src : item.media.m.replace('_m.','.')}).appendTo("#pics");
                if ( i == 10 ) {
                    $('#pics').coinslider();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
});
```

and my main file

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title></title>
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
    <p id="pics">
    </p>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Check you have included js for `coinslider`. In your HTML file we are not looking any `js` for `coinslider`.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$('document')
```

to this:

```
$(document)
```

You should not wrap the document keyword with any quotes.

---

also it may be a path issue as i see you have a `js` folder referenced and you have not included the coinslider js lib, so the issue might be here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="thePath4CoinSlider.js"></script>
```

may be you have put all the js files in the js folder and you are not referencing them from there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

check the src in the above script.

Comment: I downloaded a plugin from jquery.com to that gives me the coinslider method link here http://plugins.jquery.com/coin-slider/  I think my main thought was that I thought the coinslider method was just included in jquery like the hide method and realized that I could only use the method if I downloaded the plugin from that link lol my bad

Comment: ohh! now you have to download it and include in your page and then you are good to go.